# Akka Streams RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff stop condition

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm using RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff to restart the Source if there's an exception, but I would like to stop (cancel) the restarts if a certain exception type is received. For example:

```
RestartSource
  .onFailuresWithBackoff(
    minBackoff = 1,
    maxBackoff = 5,
    randomFactor = 0.2,
    maxRestarts = 3
  ) { () => 
    val responseFuture = doSomeAsyncTask().recover {
      case SomeSpecialError =>
        // I want to quit from the restarts
      case NonFatal(ex) => 
        // Re-throw so that the Source is restarted
        throw ex
    }

    Source
      .future(responseFuture)
      .mapAsync(parallelism = 1)(Future.successful(_))
}
```

I've tried to set a Supervision strategy on both the wrapped Source and the RestartSource, but the event never reaches to it. For this reason, the same explanation goes for trying to do this on the Sink operator.

Answer (score 2):

From the `RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff` docs, all you need is for the source to complete (without emitting anything) to prevent a restart from happening.

One way to accomplish this is to, if `doSomeAsyncTask` results in a `Future[T]`, to map it into a `Future[Option[T]]` and then recover the distinguished failure into a successful `None`.  Then in the stream source:

- if the original future failed with some other exception, the source will fail and be restarted
- if the original future failed with the distinguished exception, we filter that out so the source completes without emitting anything
- if the original future succeeded, we pass that value through normally

For example:

```
RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(
  // yada yada yada
) { () =>
  val baseFuture = doSomeAsyncTask().map(Option(_))
  val tweakedFuture = baseFuture.recoverWith {
    case SomeSpecialError => Future.successful(None)
    case NonFatal(e) => baseFuture  // including for clarity
  }

  Source.future(tweakedFuture)
    .mapConcat(_.toList)  // swallows the None arising from `SomeSpecialError`
    // the mapAsync in your question is pointless, so I've omitted it,
    // but if it's a placeholder for something else, you'd put it here
}
```

The above assumes that `doSomeAsyncTask()` never results in a successful `null`, but since `null`s aren't supposed to be passed through an Akka Stream and you're not handling that, that's probably a reasonably safe assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I was indeed completing it but it felt a bit hacky, and that's why I wanted another solution if possible. Anyway, your solution is cleaner than mine, so I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to handle it, is to use `RestartSettings`:

```scala
private val restartSettings = RestartSettings(
  minBackoff = 3.seconds,
  maxBackoff = 30.seconds,
  randomFactor = 0.2
)
  .withMaxRestarts(3, 1.hour)  // should always reach the 3 counts within 1 hour
  .withRestartOn {
    case sse: SomeSpecialError => 
      log error ("Didn't restart because of SomeSpecialError", sse)
      false  // don't restart
    case _ => 
      true  // restart
  }

RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(restartSettings) { () =>
    Source
      .future(responseFuture)
      .mapAsync(parallelism = 1)(Future.successful(_))
}
```